# Undefined type 'Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations'

Tags: laravel

I tried to include the use  (HasTranslations) in my Models but I have issues

> Unspecified type "Spatie \ Translatable \ HasTranslations".

Although I wrote this:

```
use Spatie \ Translatable \ HasTranslations;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no spaces in between:

```php
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;
```

Comment: No, I didn't put spaces in but the post appeared like this, is there a solution

Comment: Did you already run `composer require spatie/laravel-translatable`?

Comment: If you haven't done that already, follow the installation guidelines here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable